# ADF git configuration error: You are not allowed to save to current branch, either select another branch, or resolve the permissions in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

When configuring a repository for my Azure Data Factory I am receiving the following error:

```
Failed to save Publish branch.
Error: You are not allowed to save to current branch, either select another branch, or resolve the permissions in Azure DevOps.
```

[image]

The only non-standard feature that I have selected is to use a custom "Publish branch".

I have checked all permissions and made sure the branch exists in Azure DevOps.

Comment: Check the permission in your github account, you need to explicitly give the permission to adf and then only you will be able to save in git branch. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#already-connected-to-github-using-a-personal-account

Comment: @RahulShukla As mentioned above I have all permissions needed, the reason it was throwing the error was because I was attempting to save to a branch name that was not adf_publish. As stated in the answer to save to a branch that was not called adf_publish you need to use the json file - once that was in place it saved without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It transpires that if you use a "Publish branch" which is not called adf_publish you need to create a publish_config.json file in the root folder of the collaboration branch (develop in this example).

```
{
    "publishBranch": "adf_publish_dnh"
}
```

Its just the error message is not very helpful!

More detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#configure-publishing-settings

Answer (score 0):

An option to work around this, is to disconnect from Git and then reconnect to the correct publishing branch.
(Having the branch name in the repo complicates CI/CD process.)